# Hardcode password in application.yml Fortify issue

Tags: spring-boot, passwords, datasource, fortify

I have bellow properties in my spring boot application.yml file for data source. but in my fortify scan I am getting issue for **Password Management: Hardcoded password**. can anyone help me how I can fix this issue.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url:"datasource url"
    username:user
    password:ENC(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```